# What's the right sequence?

Tags: clauses

Does it make sense if I say:

> This is the right order of the person to contact"?

I'm translating a document about a matrix escalation, which allows you to specify multiple user contacts to be notified in the event of critical issues. I have a list of points of contact and there is a clear sequence to follow, so I want to explain to our customers that they have to follow the order.

there is a list of persons, each person has a "mark" that is L (for ex. L1, L2, L3 ecc.). I have to explain that "L" stands for the right order to contact the persons"
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you reveal some context? What is "a list of points of contact?"

Comment: I'm translating a document about a matrix escalation, which allows you to specify multiple user contacts to be notified in the event of critical issues. These contact details are presented to the service delivery NOC while creating or updating a service ticket. You can notify the right people at the right time about critical alerts irrespective of the business hours.

Comment: Does it mean that many person**s** have to be contacted in a particular (right) order?

Comment: Did you want to say: "This is the right order to contact the person**s** (or maybe users, customers, clients)." ?

Comment: there is a list of persons, each one has a "mark" that is L (for ex. L1, L2, L3 ecc.). I have to explain that "L" stands for the right order to contact the persons"

Comment: As hinted in earlier comments, the only thing that's wrong with the sentence is that it should be ***persons*** (plural) not ***person*** (singular). (You use the plural at the end of your question, so it may have just been a typo.) Also note that while there's nothing wrong with *persons*, *people* is the more natural plural form.

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't quite grammatically correct, or idiomatic.

A clearer way of expressing this would be:

> The Level code (L1 etc) denotes the order in which persons should be contacted.

However, if you think the intended audience will understand the terminology, this is sometimes referred to within a business organisation as an *order of escalation*:

> The Level code (L1 etc) denotes the order of *escalation*.

Comment: there is a list of persons, each person has a "mark" that is L (for ex. L1, L2, L3 ecc.). I have to explain that "L" stands for the right order to contact the persons"

Comment: @LaviniaRomani Wouldn't it be easier and less confusing if you listed the persons in the order intended rather than have a separate coding system to denote the order?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't :( The only thing I can do is a legend where I explain what L stands for